# How to get the document id from a firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to Angular, and I have a problem. I don't know how to get the document id that I've just created and use it right next to it. I have seen that there are two options `db.collection('info').doc().set()` and `db.collection('info').add()`.

For now I have tried this code:

```
var DocID:string;
db.collection().add({
   description: info
  }).then(function(docRef){
   DocID = docRef.id;
  }).catch(function(error){
   console.log("Error creating the document:", error);
});
IdInfo.push(DocID);
```

I need to store in the array all the Ids from the documents, althought some times I get it done and others I get an error `undefined`. I don't know which is the best way to create a new document and add data to it, receiving the document id.

Thank you for the help!!

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add()` returns a `Promise`, therefore you can use `then()` that will contain a callback which will be called when the `Promise` is fulfilled. Since `Promise` is used in asynchronous operations, then here `IdInfo.push(DocID);` you will get undefined since the data is still not fully retrieved. You need to add the above code inside the `then()` to be able to add the `docID` inside the array:

```
db.collection().add({
   description: info
  }).then(function(docRef){
   DocID = docRef.id;
   IdInfo.push(DocID);
  }).catch(function(error){
   console.log("Error creating the document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both options are functionally equivalent.  Choose the one that you prefer.

If you use `add()`, it will return a DocumentReference with the generated document ID.  If you use `doc()` (before calling `set()`), it will also return a DocumentReference (before writing the document with `set()`).  Be sure to read the API documentation for each method to understand what they do.